# Convolution Layer Filter Map combination

Tags: python, pytorch, convolution

If i have a very simple 2d Convolution Layer in pytorch let's say:

```py
nn.Conv2d(2, 3, 1, groups=1, padding=0, bias=False)
```

As i understand from the [pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html#conv2d) if one set `groups=1` all inputs are convolved to all outputs. This means for each Output there are 2 Feature Maps which needed to be combined somehow. I expected this would be somehow an addition of the two Feature Maps but this seems not to be the case.
Does anyone know how the two Feature Maps are merged into one technically?

Answer (score 0):

With `groups=1` you have the default behavior, in which each filter (you have 3 of them) considers all the input channels (2, in your case).  Instead, with `groups=2` happens that half input channels are convolved with half output channels: in your case 3 is not divisible by 2, so you *can't* have `groups=2`. This implies a 2x reduction in learnable parameters, since you combine half the input with half the filters.

Basically `groups > 1` allows to implement a *Grouped convolution*, which is as if using multiple *smaller* convolutions on an evenly divided input.

Anyway, for whatever value of `groups` you always get *one* output tensor of size `N x 3 x H x W`, since you have 3 output filters.

> Does anyone know how the two Feature Maps are merged into one technically?

The output of the various groups are concatenated to get the final feature map. Because is as if multiple `nn.Conv2d(2, 3 // groups, 1)` where applied to `2 // groups` input channels.

Comment: Hi Luca thank you for your reply. What i would like to know is how the concatenation works technically under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution now. The Feature Maps are summed up as it is done within a Dense Layer.
The Theory can be found in detail [under convolution demo](https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv)

And a proof within [this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TYd2ef_9XIzGaaoK3h9kDt6z80MiMZ39?usp=sharing)